# SCJP program giving output 8 2 how?

Tags: java, scjp, post-increment, pre-increment

```
class Foozit {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer x = 0;
        Integer y = 0;
        for (Short z = 0; z < 5; z++) {
            if ((++x > 2) || ++y > 2)
                x++;
        }
        System.out.println(x + "Hello World!" + y);
    }
}
```

I tried this scjp piece of code and I am getting the output 5 3 can anyone tell me where i am going wrong

Comment: What do you mean, "going wrong"? It outputs what it outputs--what's the question?

Comment: I think OP's problem is "dry-run this program and determine its output" OP is getting 5 3 and doesn't know why the program in fact prints 8 2. All this proves to me is that SCJP is an exercise in frustration and futility. What practical relevance does this problem have? If I saw this in producton code, I'd make sure to wring that dev's ear.

Answer (score 6):

The loop executes 5 times (z from 0 to 4)

In the if condition, ++x is evaluated all five times. But ++y is evaluated only when first part of condition is false.

i.e., This condition:

```
if ((++x > 2) || ++y > 2)
```

becomes:

```
//1st iteration 
if( 1 > 2 || 1 > 2 ) //False, x++ is not evaluated

//2nd iteration
if( 2 > 2 || 2 > 2 ) //False, x++ is not evaluated

//3rd iteration 
if( 3 > 2 || 2 > 2 ) //True, the second ++y is skipped, but x++ is evaluated, x becomes 4

//4th iteration 
if( 5 > 2 || 2 > 2 ) //True, the second ++y is skipped, but x++ is evaluated, x becomes 6

//5th iteration
if( 7 > 2 || 2 > 2 ) //True, the second ++y is skipped, but x++ is evaluated, x becomes 8
```

So finally, we have:

```
x = 8 and y = 2
```

Remember: ++x is pre-increment (think change-and-use) while x++ is post-increment(think use-and-change)

Comment: Thank you Mr. vaisakh for giving clear explanation on pre-increment and post-increment along with each flow step by step and on OR operator .Thank u for reminding me rules of OR operator..